# Can RTP payload type be changed in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

I'm using ffmpeg to generate an RTP stream for testing purposes, but I need to change the RTP payload type to 107. Currently, it's 96.

This is the command I use to generate the stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.h264 -an -c:v copy -f rtp -sdp_file localhost.sdp "rtp://127.0.0.1:1234"
```

Is it possible to change the payload type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-payload_type 107` before the output url, like: `... -payload_type 107 "rtp://..."`