# How to set RTP payload type in libavformat?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtp, libav, libavformat

I am trying to write a video streaming application using libavformat. While ffmpeg and libavformat gives 96 & 97 as default payload types, I want to specify custom RTP payload type. I already know how to set it in ffmpeg's command line, as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833356/can-rtp-payload-type-be-changed-in-ffmpeg/70740075#70740075), however I want to give it inside the code. I tried the following:

```
AVFormatContext *ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
ctx->oformat = av_guess_format("rtp", NULL, NULL);
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options, "payload_type", "128", 0);
//Assume url is set here
avio_open2(&ctx->pb, ctx->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, &options);
```

However it does not work. Any suggestions how to set RTP payload type in libavformat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtp` is a muxer in libavformat, not a protocol, so the options are passed to `avformat_write_header`.

Comment: I tried what you've sadi, so I passed the AVDictionary struct to the muxer's avformat_write_header, however I still get payload types 96 & 97.

Comment: 127 is the upper limit.

Comment: I just wrote a random number as an example, the actual value I want to use is less than 127.

Comment: I was looking to a wrong place, now it is OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cydonia, please share the eventual solution